# Duplicate Script Managers

Tags: asp.net, webforms, scriptmanager

I'm working on an ASP.Net webforms app, and I've run into a unique issue. There is a script manager for an update panel on the MasterPage, as well as a script manager in a sub-page calling the master page. This as i'm sure you will note cause an exception to be thrown and crash the webapp.

I've tried programatically excluding the scriptmanager + update panel from the code as follows:

```
<% If Not (Result.RawURL.Contains("ExcludedPageDirectory") Then %>
<!-- all that code goes here -->
<% End If%>
```

However I think just the presence of the script manager tag in the source is causing the error. How would I programatically handle this?

Comment: In the 6+ years I do ASP.NET, I _never_ used `<%`. I always think this is "old style" (ASP) and breaks the idea behind ASP.NET.

Comment: admittedly, it's a dirty hack from necessity

Comment: @Uwe avoiding bee sting syntax is just shooting yourself in the foot. Just because it *can* be abused doesn't mean it should never be used.

Comment: @Rex Thank you, sounds reasonable. Same as for `goto` and similar "tools".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A page can contain only one ScriptManager control in its hierarchy. To register services and scripts for nested pages, user controls, or components when the parent page already has a ScriptManager control, use the [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx) control (Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx))

Comment: This warrants more investigation, thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You don't require a script manager again in the page if you have it in the master page.
Remove it and try

Comment: It breaks the functionality of the update panels in the sub page

Answer (score 0):

I ended up duplicating the master page and left out the update panel/scriptmanager code. This seems to have been the most elegant solution for the given situation. However I feel that the ScriptManagerProxy answer held the best possible solution had the duplication of the masterpage not been possible.